# Need to capture part of file name into variable

Tags: shell, sed, grep, regular-expression, aix

I have bunch of CSV files named like so in a directory:

```
 s_m_u_supplemental_fields_account_9_4_2015_11_26_Error.csv
 s_m_u_supplemental_fields_account_9_4_2015_12_3_Error.csv
 s_m_u_academic_status_loa_8_29_2015_0_1_Error.csv
```

I need to capture the "s_m_u_academic_status_loa" part to append to a column inside the file. I tested the expression `"s/^\(s_([^_0-9]+_)+\)\([^\.]+\.csv\)$/\1/"` in RegEx Tester online and does capture what I need, but for some reason it fails to work from AIX ksh.

Here is my script so far (AIX 6.2):

```
#!/bin/ksh

ls *_Error.csv | while read i
do
    echo ${i}
    edfilename = `echo ${i} |sed -e "s/^\(s_([^_0-9]+_)+\)\([^\.]+\.csv\)$/\1/"`
    echo ${edfilename}
done
```

Comment: there must be no spaces around "=" when doing variable=value assignment

Comment: I'd also _strongly_ recommend you double quote your variables when you use them. For example `echo "$edfilename"` instead of just `echo $edfilename`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try this version of your script so far

```
#!/bin/ksh
ls *_Error.csv | while read i
do  echo "${i}"
    edfilename=$(echo "${i}" | sed -e 's/^\(s_([^_0-9]*_)*\)\([^\.]*\.csv\)$/\1/')
    echo "${edfilename}"
done
```

I dont think aix sed understands `+` so I've replaced them with `*`. If
you really need `+` then use `\{1,\}` which may work on aix.

A simpler pattern that should suffice: `'s/\([^0-9]*\)_.*/\1/'`

Comment: Thanks @meuh The simplified pattern works. I didn't realize AIX doesn't like +!

Comment: Arrrgghhh!  Don't parse the output of `ls`; just do `for i in *_Error.csv`.

Comment: @Scott I prefer to minimise changes to an OP script to avoid problems in case they have reduced their code just to expose their difficulty. For example, `ls` and pipe will act differently if the glob finds no matching files. A `for` loop would need `shopt -s nullglob` to work the same way.

Comment: Using `ls -d` would stop descent into directories (if present). A change of `atom+` to `atom*` should really become `atom atom*` to ensure that _at least one_ applies.